# What kind of information do recruiting companies keep?

Tags: interviewing, feedback, recruiter

What kind of information do recruiting companies keep, apart from those we enter in the registration form?

Recently, I had an interview with a company, which was arranged through a recruiting company. There was a little communication problem (about the time of phone interview), and I think they were a little offended.

Do they give any feedback from the company to the recruiters? And is that feedback is used "against me" in future proposals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recruiting company is in the business of placing qualified people in paying positions.  Following up is absolutely part of the process as the recruiter generally will only make money if one of their candidates is hired into the position.  They may have one or several candidates in line for the position and they usually solicit feedback from varying levels of formality with the company.   Usually a recruiter new to a given company will spend more time solidifying the contact with the company staff to make sure that they are meeting the company's needs.

Ideally, the recruiter is looking to both improve his own communication with the company as well as making better selections in the type of candidates the company recieves.  In a perfect world, the company won't blame the screw up of the recruiter upon the interviewee - for example, when an Interviewee doesn't get the info that the recruiter should have passed along - but it's not a 100% perfect system.

How the recruiter takes the feedback is another story.  Ideally, a recruiter will realize that if the communication got confused, they had a part to play - but each person and company is different.

How long and how diligently a recruiter tracks and maintains this info is another story - one that is very much dependant on each recruiter.  Long ago, I worked with recruiters who assimilated a very accurate profile of me as a candidate, and did an excellent job at recognizing my strengths and weaknesses - it was very personal and I had a 1 on 1 contact.  Lately, I've had cases were recruiters don't seem to talk to each other or keep a shared data store of any type - because a "do not call" request to one recruiter does not stop the onslaught of spam-like emails from his collegues... so mileage here is highly variable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, recruiting companies will follow up with the company after an interview to get feedback. And they *will* use that feedback to tailor whom they connect you with.

Usually that means finding a position that is a better fit for your skills/personality, but can be a negative thing if the feedback was very poor. After all, you're their "product" and they don't want to associate unprofessional or otherwise unflattering candidates with their company.

Comment: Other companies have access to those data?

Comment: @peraueb8921 - It's often not _data_. The recruiter will simply fail to submit your name to other companies, or will behave differently to the other companies (perhaps give a less glowing recommendation, perhaps caution the company about the perceived problem, etc).

Comment: They may also use the feedback to prep you for the next interview. For instance if the feedback was that you were late (Which is huge no-no in interviewing), they might warn you not to do that again. If you failed FizzBuzz, they might not want to send you to another company that uses it until you can prove you can solve it. Remember recruiters only get paid when they place someone. They often do not earn an hourly wage. So they want to send in people who have a chance to get placed. If what you did was too negative, they could drop you from consideration.

Comment: I dont know. something urgent happened some minutes before the interview and I couldn answer the phone(no signal). I explained and apologised. What do you think?

Comment: @peraueb8921 That's fine. Everyone understands that stuff like that happens. As long as it isn't a trend, most people won't cause much fuss over it.